# .displayed? .exist? all functions are throwing Timeout::Error instead of returning false

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, pageobjects, page-object-gem

I am using cucumber, page-object and selenium webdriver to automate an application having nested iframes. Now to check if an element exist, I am using below code:

```
@current_page.send(my_element + '_element').exists?
```

Instead of returning false above code is throwing Timeout::Error error. I also tried directly with selenium functions but same issue

```
@browser.switch_to.frame(0)
@browser.find_element(:id => 'some_id').displayed?
@browser.switch_to.default_content
```

I've set up the time outs in my env.rb and hooks.rb as below:

```
TIME_OUT = 180
PageObject.default_page_wait = TIME_OUT
PageObject.default_element_wait = TIME_OUT

client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.timeout = TIME_OUT

@browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for(browser.to_sym, :http_client => client)
@browser.manage.window.maximize
@browser.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = TIME_OUT
@browser.manage.timeouts.page_load = TIME_OUT
@browser.manage.timeouts.script_timeout = TIME_OUT
```

Comment: Can you post the error stack trace?

Comment: there is no trace.. just Timeout::Error (Timeout::Error).... and this will point to my above written code

Comment: It will likely help if you can share a page that reproduces the problem.

Comment: yea I understand but I am on a client machine and can't share the application. Will see if i can find some other url